# Generic lists in web references

Tags: reference, generic-list

I have a generic response object.  This object accepts a type (this will be either an object or a generic list) and contains a generic object and some error information:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Response<T>
    {
        [DataMember]
        public T ReturnObject { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string StackTrace { get; set; }

        public void SetErrorInformation(string message, string stackTrace)
        {
            ErrorMessage = message;
            StackTrace = stackTrace;
        }
    }
```

I an attempting to pass this object with the needed information through a WCF service.  This works fine until I pass a list as the type.  The web reference turns the list into an array so when I attempt to use it as a list it cannot convert types.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the reference to your service in visual studio, click on the advanced button on the add service dialog. Here you can change collection type from array to list.